# Noah Versus Utnapishtim

Tags: bible

There are two Great Flood legends: one in the Bible involving Noah, and one in Sumerian mythology. Multiple  civilizations and cultures have a flood legend, so does that add historical credence to the possibility that a flood did happen, or is it just plain old legend plagiarism?

Comment: Please share your Reason for your downvotes

Comment: This is again a simple question you could have answered by simply looking up the issue on Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh_flood_myth

Comment: how does the wiki answer who borrowed who's legend about the bible or the second question of historical credence my comparison is not addressed at all neither is the question of credence

Comment: Firstly , the older legend can not have borrowed from the younger legend. Secondly, that the Biblical myth is descendant from the Babylonian one is stated in no uncertain terms in the Wikipedia article on the myth in question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah%27s_Ark#Origins_of_the_Genesis_Ark_story

Comment: The question of credence is a separate question (and you should really have separate questions for them) but in any case it has already been answered: The biblical stories are stories with no facts supporting them. The lack of evidence (and hence credence) is also stated in the article on Noah's ark.

Comment: edited thw question to one not on wiki thanks for the feedback

Comment: Sorry, this one is on the Wiki to. The article for Noah's Ark clearly states that the myth of Noah is derived from the Babylonian myth.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not history.

Comment: Many scientists now believe that the Black Sea basin flooded shortly before the beginning of recorded history, and subsequent to the last Ice Age. If correct this could easily have given rise to flood legends in the Middle East.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story of [Utnapishtim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh_flood_myth) is adapted from the story about [Atrahasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atra-Hasis), which in turn is probably adapted from the earlier Babylonian flood myths. The same goes for the story in the bible. So to answer your question: Yes, it's "legendary plagiarism".

As to your original question, as these Babylonian flood myths are at least one thousand years older than the Biblical one, it is pretty obvious who copied from whom.

There is no doubt that a flood did happen. Floods happen all the time. There is no single shred of evidence that a *global* or biblical flood ever happened, and there most assuredly has never been any big flood created by a god to kill all of mankind except a few, with these few surviving because they were forewarned and built a boat. That is a children's story created not to be believed as fact, but to convey a moral.